# Sidekiq stop one single, running job

Tags: jobs, sidekiq, cancellation

So I need to stop a **running** Job in Sidekiq (3.1.2) programmatically, not a scheduled one. I did read the API documentation but didn't really find anything about cancelling running jobs. Is this possible with sidekiq?

When this is not directly possible, my idea was to circumvent this, by raising an exception in the job when I call the signal, then deleting the job from the retryset. This is clearly not optimal though.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you resolve this problem then? Could you share your workaround?

Comment: Look at the FAQ from the first answer, it explains the idea really well. I did something similar by adding multiple breakpoints to the perform action, (i.e. at the beginning of an each block). Thats pretty much dependent on your use case, where/when you want to stop execution of your perform method

Answer (score 14):

Correct, the only way to stop a job is for the job to stop itself.  Your application must implement that logic.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-cancel-a-sidekiq-job

Comment: Could you please elaborate on it a little more? I don't know how to stop a job by itself

Comment: Wow, I actually implented something similar to this version by using Redis and storing all jids in a hash, then adding breakpoints in my perform method, each time checking whether the current jid was set in redis

Comment: Any opposition to killing the thread, as suggested in another answer, when it is desired to interrupt the job?

Comment: If that method was safe, don't you think Sidekiq would allow it?

Comment: looking at the above link, I reckon that once we call the `setex` function, the job's status is set to `cancelled` and it stops executing. Now, when this job attempts to run again, then, the `return if cancelled?` part effectively completes/ends the job. Is that a correct interpretation? @MikePerham

Answer (score 7):

If you know the long running job's Thread ID, its possible to terminate it from another task:

```rb
class ThreadLightly
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(tid)
    puts "I'm %s, and I'll be terminating TID: %s..." % [self.class, tid]
    Thread.list.each {|t|
      if t.object_id.to_s == tid
        puts "Goodbye %s!" % t
        t.exit
      end
    }
  end
end
```

You can trigger it from the [sidekiq_pusher](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs#recurring-jobs):

```
bundle exec ./pusher.rb ThreadLightly $YOURJOBSTHREADID
```

You'll need to log the Thread.current.object_id from each job since the UI dosn't show it.  Also, if you run distributed sidekiqs, you'll need to run this task until it runs on the same instance.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for!. One little correction: at this moment (2017) you should use `object_id.to_s(36)`.

Comment: Im not sure this would work if you have sidekiq running over multiple instances. What would happen if the job you want to kill is on instance A but this worker executes on instance B? As far as I know you have no way of knowing to which process this worker will be assigned

Answer (score 4):

### Using Sidekiq Dashboard.

Another way to stop running job is, Stop the Sidekiq process.

[image]

and It will take some time to stop sidekiq process.
If the Sidekiq process stop, all job were running, will be located back to `enqued` section. so if you re-start sidekiq process, it will running again.

You need to delete all jobs in enqued section. You can do it using dashboard. or running this kind of command on rails console.

```
## queue_name = 'logger'
## Sidekiq::Queue.new(queue_name).each { |e| e.delete }

# e.g.
Sidekiq::Queue.new('logger').each { |e| e.delete }
```

Or... using dashboard...

[image]

[image]

It will be removed from the all job queue.
Now you can re-start your sidekiq process.